# Trying to run spring boot application with Oauth2 using SQLServer database connectivity

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Currently working on a Sample Spring boot application that uses SQLServer database, but having difficulty to run it without errors. Following is the compile time error I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/oauth/oserver/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at com.oauth.oserver.OserverApplication.main(OserverApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/oauth/oserver/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 28 common frames omitted

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 41 common frames omitted

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:130) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64d0eb8.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62.dataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 42 common frames omitted

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:130) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64d0eb8.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.oauth.oserver.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c68d62.dataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 42 common frames omitted

   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:127) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
```

My Application.properties file looks like this

```
 server.port=8081
 spring.datasource.url = XXXXXX
 spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
 spring.datasource.username = XXXXXX
 spring.datasource.password = XXXXXXXX
 spring.jpa.show-sql = true
 spring.jpa.open-in-view = false 
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
 spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
 spring.jpa.database=sql_server
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

And my **AppConfig.java** file:

```
package com.oauth.oserver.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

       dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("XXXXX");
       dataSource.setUsername("XXXXXX");
       dataSource.setPassword("XXXXXXX");

       return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
       return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }
}
```

I'm new to spring boot, and want help about this. Highly appreciated if someone can tell what exactly is the issue, wondering if this is a jar problem or code.

Comment: I think you dont have the driver name spelled correctly in your code. Please check the one in your class

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please upvote my comment, so it helps someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have SQLServerDriver class available at your classpath. More over drive class is located at `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`, in your code you've written `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`